# Comparing Exponentials of different rates

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $T_1$ has exponential distribution $\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda_1)$ 
and $T_2$ has exponential distribution $\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda_2)$

Assume $T_1$ = life time of refrigerator $T_2 =$ life time of Stove.

We want to find $P (T_1 < T_2)$ the probability that the refrigerator fails before the stove.

From the book "Introduction to probability" by Joseph K. Blitzstein and Jessica Hwang page 293:

its says: We just need to integrate the joint PDF of $T_1$ and $T_2$ over the appropriate region, which is all $(t_1,t_2)$ with $t_1 >0, t_2>0$ and $t_1 < t_2$

$$P(T_1 < T_2) = \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{t_2} \lambda_1 e^{- \lambda_1 t_1}  \lambda_2 e^{- \lambda_2 t_2} \,\mathrm{d}t_1 \,\mathrm{d}t_2 $$

i do not understand why the above equality is valid?

can I think of $t_1$ as random variable in the X axis and $t_2$ as random variable in the Y axis and their joint PDF is a surface lies on 3 dimension space with Z axis indicates probability. if i think of it in that way then if we do integration according to the above equality. assume $t_2 = 3$ then it is $P(T_1 < 3)$ I can find a point over an area that has been integrated ex. point (2.5 , 1) which is the point that $T_1 > T_2$ but why when we calculate $P (T_1 < T_2)$ we integrate the area in the event $T_1 > T_2$ ??? you can see the area of integration in my attached photo highlighted in blue and the point (2.5 , 1) in red colour. The Y axis is $T_2$ and the X-axis is $T_1$  this is the view from top.

[image]

please explain to me step by step. Im a newbie.

Comment: It's probably easier not to view it as a two dimensional integral, but instead as a one dimensional integral over the product of a probability and a cdf.

Answer (score 1):

The picture you created does not represent the region of integration.  The point $(2.5,1)$ is not in the region of integration.

The authors state that the region of integration satisfies the inequalities $$t_1 > 0, \quad t_2 > 0, \quad t_1 < t_2.$$  If you let $t_1$ be plotted on the horizontal axis and $t_2$ on the vertical axis, then $t_1 > 0$ is the right half plane, $t_2 > 0$ is the upper half plane, hence their intersection is the first quadrant.  Then the inequality $t_1 < t_2$ comprises those points *above* the diagonal line $t_1 = t_2$.  Thus the intersection of this region with the first quadrant **excludes** the aforementioned point.

Comment: if $t_1$ be plotted on the horizontal axis, why you said $t_1 > 0$ is the upper half plane? shouldn't it be on the right half of the plane? because if you go up or down that doesn't change the value of $t_1$ you have to go right to get positive and left to get negative. you misunderstand something? or i misunderstand something?

Comment: @user3270418 Yes, thank you for catching that error.  I will fix it shortly.

Comment: i understand the conditions that the authors are given but why the limit of integration goes from 0 to $t_2$ (for inner integration) and 0 to infinity (for outer integration)? if you look at the meaning of the integration, isn't it the same as the picture i draw? if it is, why the author make the integration and the conditions contradict with each other? it says integrate from 0 to $t_2$ on the X axis and integrate from 0 to infinity on the Y axis isn't it? and if you do that you get the picture i draw?

Comment: @user3270418 No.  What the limits of integration mean is that if you pick a particular $t_2$, then the interval of integration for $t_1$ is between $0$ and $t_2$, thus guaranteeing that $0 < t_1 < t_2$.  Geometrically, this means picking a horizontal line above the $x$-axis at $y = t_2$, then choosing the segment of that line $0 < x < t_2$.

Comment: In my area of integration, I integrate in the $dt_1$ direction from 0 to $t_2$ then I integrate the outer integral from 0 to infinity in the $dt_2$ direction which is according to the equality above. please have a look at the equality that has double integral. if you do exactly that you get the area that i draw, isn't it? which is contradict with the conditions written in the book why?

Comment: In multiple integration, the **evaluation** proceeds from the inside out, but the way the region is **specified** is outside-in.  For example, $$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^y f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$ corresponds to a region for which $x$ is always less than $y$, namely a triangle with vertices $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)$.  The notation means for each $y$ between $0$ and $1$, you are integrating $x$ between $0$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment, this solves my problem, can you please copy your comment above and paste it into your answer. I will check the green mark on it.